# Route is not triggered with trailing slash in web api 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is my route configuration:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Public",
                routeTemplate: "{dept}/{unit}/",
                defaults: new
                {                    
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index"                
                },
               constraints: new { constraint = new MyConstraint() }

            );
```

When I type into the url:

```
mysite.com/XYZ/123
```

then my constraint class is triggered

but when I use:

`mysite.com/XYZ/123/` with the appended slash the constraint class is not triggered.

I use Web Api 2.

In the routeTemplate I can use the "/" at the end or not that doesnt make difference.

Why does it not work?

**UPDATE**

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Index()
{

}

}
```

Comment: Can you show your controller too?

Comment: I updated my question with info.

Comment: I've replicated your Controller and route template (except for the constraint) and I'm not having your issue. It must be the constraint.
Can you share also the exact path you're using?

Comment: What path do you speak of? the test urls I used are posted above :-)

Comment: Ok, just seems strange that you'd use "/XYZ/123" to map to the home controller. Can you show the constraint code?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my answer:

Try attribute routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("dept")]
 public class DepartmentController : ApiController
{
   [Route("unit:int:min(1)"}]
   public object Unit() {}
}
```

Constraints can be setup like above. More:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

Comment: Sorry , but I do not understand your solution. What should I change exactly?

Comment: I just tested my own web api and a trailing slash does not affect the routing. This is for routes created with attributes, however.

I see you're using a constraint so perhaps that is having an affect.

Comment: sorry but attribute routing is not an alternative for me.